# Laravel, Intervention, Corrupt JPEG data: 1130 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9

Tags: laravel, intervention

so i give up. i have more forum windows open than i can count, have tried a bunch of different things and still no luck. i have installed intervention with laravel 5.0 and can get some images through but others (many) bomb out with the following error

ErrorException in Decoder.php line 35:
imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Corrupt JPEG data: 1130 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;
//use Intervention\Image\Image;
//use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Image;


    public function storepic($id)
    {

    $gallry=auth()->user()->galleries()->findorfail($id);

    $files = Input::file('images');
    // Making counting of uploaded images
    $file_count = count($files);

    // start count how many uploaded
    $uploadcount = 0;

   ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', true);

    $dt=Carbon::now();
    Carbon::setToStringFormat('omj_His');

    foreach($files as $file) {

        $rules = array('file' =>'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,jpg'); 

      $d=array('file'=> $file);

      $ext=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $mim=$file->getClientMimeType();


      $validator = Validator::make($d, $rules);
      if($validator->passes()){

        //save file

        $upPath = 'uploads/galleries/' . $id . '/';
        $filename = $dt . $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
        $upload_success = $file->move($upPath, $filename);

        // save to db

        $imag['oFileName']=$file->getClientOriginalName() ;
        $imag['sFileName']=$filename;
        $imag['gid']=$id;

        $pic=new Pictures($imag);
        $pic->save();

        if ($gallry['img_id']==null){
            $gallry['img_id']=$pic['pid'];
            $gallry->save();
        }
        //create thumbnail        
        $path = 'uploads/thumbs/' . $id . '/';
        // below used to all be one statement - it didn't effect it either way
        $img= Image::make($upPath . $filename);

        $img->resize(null, 100, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                $constraint->upsize();
            });

        $img->save($path . $filename);

        $uploadcount ++;
      }
    }
```

so i've tried to
1. suppress the errors with 
ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', true);
in multiple places
2. recreate image with binary, which blew the image to 5x in size
3. tried createimagefromstring as opposed to jpeg

i'm thinking/wondering
-if i'm not suppressing errors correctly.
-is the problem with the gd library as opposed to imagick. i haven't added imagick yet, but can, it just seems like a pain
-i could try to do the resize in another procedure, but that just seems to be putting off the problem

any thoughts would be appreciated. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same well known problem. Adding the ini_set as the first line of the index.php didn't work in my case.

I ended up with a try catch solution, warning the user the JPG is damaged.

```
try {
    $img = Image::make($filename);
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    my_flash_message($e->message);
}
```

Take care Exception is namespaced so you have to use the slash.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Use $e->getMessage() instead of $e->message because message is a protected property :)